# Maxscript: How to access UI controls that are defined later inside other groups in a rollout (Scripted plug-in)

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I have a simpleObject scripted plug-in where I define a parameters block and its associated rollout:

```
rollout mainParamsRollout "Main Properties"
(
    group "Group1"
    (
        dropdownlist ddl1 "ddl1" items:#("A", "B") height:4
        on ddl1  selected i do
        (
            ddl2.enabled = false    
        )
    )

    group "Group2"
    (
        dropdownlist ddl2 "ddl2" items:#("C", "D") height:4
    )   
)
```

When I try to make ddl2 disabled after a certain selection happens on ddl1, maxscript throws an exception saying that ddl2 is undefined.

I know it is possible to access ddl2 though mainParamsRollout.controls[5] but I am wondering if there is a better way. I have tried defining a local variable at the top of the scripted plugin as:

```
local ddl2
```

to make it available anywhere but this does not seem to work either. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ddl2` must be **declared** before calling it in `ddl1`'s event handler. You can order your code as such:

```
rollout mainParamsRollout "Main Properties"
(
    group "Group1"
    (
        dropdownlist ddl1 "ddl1" items:#("A", "B") height:4 
    )

    group "Group2"
    (
        dropdownlist ddl2 "ddl2" items:#("C", "D") height:4
    )   

    on ddl1 selected i do
    (
        ddl2.enabled = false    
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just add the rollout before the control like

```
mainParamsRollout.ddl.enabled = false
```

Then it doesn't matter where you call the control.

-Johan